# form validation in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, yup

I'm creating a form using yup and react hook form . the issue is the errors are triggered when sending the form but I want that the trigger will be when entering fields this is some of the code:

```
<Controller name="email"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
  render={({field}) => (
    <Input {...field} name={field.name}                                                   placeholder="email"/>
  )}
/>
  {errors.email && <span>{errors.email.message}</span>}
  <Controller name="confirmation_email"
                        ... />}
    />
    
    email: yup.string().email(format_email).required(champs_obligatoire),
    confirmation_email: yup.string()
            .oneOf([yup.ref('email'), null], 'Emails must match').required(champs_obligatoire),
    
    
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <MyForm errors={errors} control={control} t={t}/>
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
            Envoyer
          </Button>
    </form>
```

this code is from 3 files : the form and the services , thank you in advance for your help .
please I need a detailed explanation because I am new in react world.

Comment: change the state in the inputChangeHandler function, on every keystroke

Comment: @SachinYadav Thank you for your reply , Can you explain in detail please because I'm new in react :-)

Comment: You need to show what have you tried in order to get details

Comment: @Sachin Yadav I did

Comment: I've fixed formatting for code, but block in the middle does not make any sense. Like if you removed too much after copy-pasting code sample.